# DataGrid observable collection collectionchanged event

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, observablecollection

Im trying to add new record to database through collectionchanged event of the datagrid everything works fine when Im using Addrange to add new items to database but when Im looping through new items to add them with a change in value of a field it wont add anything (gives null value for each item).

```
private void RepList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                //db.PI_FitupReps.AddRange(e.NewItems.Cast<PI_FitupRep>()); Works fine but loop adds nothing
                foreach (PI_FitupRep item in e.NewItems.Cast<PI_FitupRep>())
                {
                    if (item.Fitup != null && item.Fitup != "")
                    {
                        db.PI_FitupReps.Add(new PI_FitupRep
                        {
                            Fitup = item.Fitup,
                            Unit = "4551",
                            FDate = DateTime.Now
                        });
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                db.PI_FitupReps.RemoveRange(e.OldItems.Cast<PI_FitupRep>());
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                db.PI_FitupReps.AttachRange(e.OldItems.Cast<PI_FitupRep>());
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `AddRange(e.NewItems.Cast<PI_FitupRep>())` is going to be adding the same exact objects as the `foreach` loop, so not sure why you think one is doing something different. Also, this event fires right when something has been added to the collection, so the user still hasn't had time to fill in any information. `Fitup` will be `null` unless you specified a default value for it because it was just created. Long story short, you should not be using this event to add new items to your database.

Comment: I think the same it should be same result but when I use addrange I get records added after clicking save button but when using loop method nothing added to the database.